# how to get a Token from InstanceID in GCM

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

I am learning how to send and receive push notifications via `GCM`, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-push-notification-using-gcm-tutorial/)

and there is a class called `GCMRegistrationIntentService` posted below. concerning the following line:

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
//Getting the token from the instance id
token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

what is `R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId)`? I tried to find it in `strings.xml`, but such an entry was not available

could please clarify and explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCM defaultSenderID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694817/gcm-defaultsenderid)

Comment: in other way you can use fcm instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use FirebaseInstanceIdService to get token.. like bellow

```
       public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {


     @Override
       public void onTokenRefresh() {
         String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();


      }
   }
```

Don't forget to add bellow code to andoridmainfest.xml

```
  <service android:name=".FirebaseIDService" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

That string contains your `project_number` and is auto-generated by Gradle based on your `google-services.json` file:

> The main result of the JSON processing is to produce two XML files
>   which you can reference as Android resources in your Java code. Below
>   is an example of each file:
>
> **app/build/generated/res/google-services/{build_type}/values/values.xml**

Source: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin