# What is INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I just started working on google cloud messaging. I downloaded a sample from [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git). In the RegistrationIntnentService to get token from GCM Server we do

```
InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

and I don't understand what scope INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE defines on GCM Server.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging#INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE) it says

> "Specifies scope used in obtaining GCM registrationToken when calling
>   getToken(String, String)
>
> Constant Value: "GCM""

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740527/why-is-my-own-sender-id-getting-back-an-invalidregistration-message) the correct answer marked says

> Note that you must use GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE as the second parameter - InstanceID is more general than just GCM, hence why it is a parameter that can take any String, but GCM specifically requires that authorization scope.

From what I understand from this is that you cannot replace INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE argument with a value other then "GCM" but I changed it and it is still receiving messages from GCM connection server.

Any help or documentation or link will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sending the message to the token generated with the non GCM scope?

Comment: I did try that and it worked (strangely) although as I mentioned earlier if I understood the statement correctly then client should not have received message at all.

Comment: What did you use as your non GCM scope?

Comment: I don't remember now... whatever it was I used it to check if my understanding was correct, and then I changed it back to INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE.
Further more doing some more research I found out that the value describes the scope of operation for the client on the GCM server.
And its even more confusing because then it never should've worked.

Comment: So either I luckily set the scope as some operation already defined or whatever. Or ....... (I am confused!)

Comment: I understand your confusion but it is really difficult to reproduce the issue if you cannot remember the non GCM scope you used. When I provide a non GCM scope and send messages to the generated token the messages are not received, which is the expected behaviour.